# T-Mobile Account and Connecting Laptop to 3G Options

Tags: wireless-networking

I know that I can use the webconnect USB stick by T-Mobile but it cost $250 which is pretty high. Is there any other way I can use my T-Mobile 3G to connect to the web using my laptop.

Comment: What's the cell brand?

Comment: Actually my cell phone is ancient. It is a prepaid cell phone which is available for $20 in wallmart. I just need a way to plug something into my laptop while I am in a bus and get 3G coverage. I do have a 3g data plan with T-mobile.

Comment: This is what T-Mobile is offering. Little pricey for me! => http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/Plans/cell-phone-plans-detail.aspx?tp=tb1&rateplan=T-Mobile-webConnect-Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3G on your cellphone, you might be able to tether them, and have the laptop use your phone's 3G connection.  You need a 3G radio to make the connection, so it either needs to be built in, or provided externally (USB or cell phone).  You can get more information on this stuff from [EVDO info](http://evdoinfo.com).  Note, I have no connection to them, other than being a happy customer of their store.  They have been around for a while, and seem to know what they are taking about.

Comment: I don't have 3g on my cell phone. I just have 3g service.

Comment: Do you mean that you are paying for a data plan, but your phone isn't 3G capable?  Or your phone indicates that it is in a 3G area, but you don't have a plan?

Comment: actually I am not paying my company is and my phone is not 3g capable.

Comment: Then your only option is to buy a 3G modem.

Comment: Do you think any 3G modem will work with T-Mobile service?

Comment: Only ones authorized to use T-Mobile will work.  Check out the EVDO Info link, they have T-Mobile specific forums that will answer your questions better than can be done here.